# Translating html input into cake php input convention

Tags: cakephp

I am having an issue with my submit button and I think its because I just left it in the regular format `echo $this->Form->end('Submit')` but actually I want to translate these properties into CakePHP  `<input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submitrating" class="button"/>` .

How can I create those properties on the submit button in CakePHP html helper form?, I am switching from a conventional php website to cake php.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can add attributes by [passing them as an array](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1389/Closing-the-Form).

```
$this->Form->end(
    array(
        'label' => 'Submit',
        'name'  => 'submitrating',
        'class' => 'button'
    )
);
```

Comment: No. See also [the API](http://api.cakephp.org/class/form-helper#method-FormHelperend) which explains this quite well with a lot of examples.